# Administrator account that can not take ownership

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions

I want to use 3 accounts:

- normal user,
- restricted administrator for installing things and
- a full administrator.

This way installers which require admin rights still can't take ownership and read some restricted folders available only to the full administrator account.

I need this because I want to isolate a cryptowallet app data so that it can't be stolen when I install a game for example. But I don't know if it's possible to forbid installer administrator to take ownership of anything he wants. How can it be achieved?

Comment: There isn’t a “restricted administrator” on Windows. A user either has elevated permission or it doesn’t. Your concept of three users isn’t possible on Windows

Comment: If possible, it may be wise to store your wallet on a device that is not used for every day use.

Comment: @Gantendo - It wouldn't help in this case. A Local Administrator on a machine can take ownership of any file.  One exception is a folder like WindowsApps, but even in that example, it's still possible, just with serious ramifications on system stability. and perhaps more difficult than the average bear. Unless you are talking about treating the storage as "cold storage" in terms of storing the wallet. Which doesn't help if the author is actively trying to mine the cryptocurrency.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done : A user is an administrator or not, there is nothing
in between.
Also, installing a product usually requires the installer to run as
administrator, so it can surely steal your wallet.

If you wish to lock away your wallet, use a product such as
[VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/code/VeraCrypt/)
to encrypt it with password.
However, take every precaution not to lose your wallet in case that
some disk failure will destroy the encryption, so keep an
unencrypted version of the file on some external backup media,
as well as the password and recovery media for VeraCrypt.